# How do I Redirect and Show Content with same urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a maybe simple Problem. I have serveral URLs that needed to be redirected in this way:

if the URL "/abc/" is called, it should show the content located under "xyz.html"

i can do that with

```
RewriteRule abc$ xyz.html
```

but "xyz.html" should be 301 redirecting to "/abc" if it is called.

This is my simple problem i am searching for an solution since hours.

it would be easy if its like "test.html" and /test/. i can do it like

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

But in my case i have a bunch of URLs with no pattern.

All i tried results to server misconfiguration.
Can you help me with that one sample?

thanks, kanuddel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /xyz.html [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz\.html/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /abc/? [R=301,L]
```

***Detailed Explanation:***

***Why there is redirection loop with normal rule writing:*** Question from OP is interesting and contradictory(kind of), why because lets say we write 1st rule to redirect(in backend) from `abc` url to `xyz.html` it will work fine. But then when we write our 2nd rule which is to rewrite url from `xyz.html` to `abc/` which is exactly opposite of first rule. Hence it becomes a loop, ASAP 1st rules gets served it reaches out to 2nd rule and it serves it back to 1st rule thus a REDIRECTION INFINITE LOOP(till 50 cycles or so).

***How to prevent redirection loop?***

- First since both rules are exactly opposite of each other so in a normal rule writing it will become a loop, now how could we prevent it to become a loop? Answer is using: `RewriteCond`(explained in next step)
- I have used an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE named `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` which will have any redirection status in its value. 2 things we need to understand about this variable.

  1- Without any request redirection its default value is NULL.

  2- Whenever we do a successful redirection its value becomes 200(NON ZERO), which we can make use of in our conditions part.

***Detailed explanation of htaccess Rules:***

- Now coming to the condition explanation part: In RewriteRule`RewriteRule ^(.*) /xyz.html [L]` I have NOT done any rewriting of url on browser why because of the THUMB RULE that we always want to show USER FRIENDLY URLs to users, so environment variable `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` will always be ZERO here.
- Coming to 2nd RewriteRule now `RewriteRule ^(.*) /abc/? [R=301,L]` where user already using a user NON-friendly URL so first thing is I need to rewrite URL in browser to user friendly url hence `R=301`(redirection with permanent flag is used here). Once Redirection happens through this condition, 1st condition will start failing now why because that checks if `REDIRECT_STATUS` variable is NULL which is NOT after serving redirection from 2nd condition. Hence this is how it prevents loop by this small trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great Explanation!

I tried it with a second URL, where "/xxx/" should show "zzz.html" But this gave me an Misonfiguration. I tried to shorten it like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /xyz.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xxx/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /zzz.html [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz\.html/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /abc/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/zzz\.html/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /xxx/? [R=301,L]
```